# MySQL - Select only records with same ID and specific value in another column

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I am trying to find a solution for removing a specific category from hundreds of products in WooCommerce via SQL. Unfortunately Wordpress core still can't do this and I haven't found any plugin or code for bulk editing categories of WooCommerce products.

I'm new to SQL and tried to put together some queries I've found here but none of them are working properly.

I'm sure more people will find this topic really helpful if anyone knows the answer.

My products have multiple categories so the table looks like this:

```
object_id  term_taxonomy_id
1          10
1          20
1          30
2          10
2          30
3          20
3          30
3          40
4          10
4          20
```

I want to filter products which have both category 10 and 20..

```
object_id  term_taxonomy_id
1          10
1          20
4          10
4          20
```

..and then select only rows with value 20 so the output should be this:

```
object_id  term_taxonomy_id
1          20
4          20
```

I hope what I'm trying to achieve is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using an exists subquery which checks for objects with taxinomy id = 10:

```
select t1.object_id, t1.term_taxonomy_id
from yourtable t1
where t1.term_taxonomy_id=20
    and exists (select 1
                from yourtable t2
                where t2.term_taxonomy_id=10 and t2.object_id=t1.object_id)
```

You can use a self join or an `in()` subquery, but exists is usually faster since it does not need to fetch the data the 2nd time.

Answer (score 0):

This will select the duplicate rows:

```
SELECT
    object_id, term_taxonomy_id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY
    object_id, term_taxonomy_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to filter this is through join:

```
SELECT t.object_id, t.term_taxonomy_id
FROM yourtable t
    INNER JOIN yourtable t1 
        ON t.object_id = t1.object_id
        AND t1.term_taxonomy_id = 10
WHERE t.term_taxonomy_id = 20
```

That would let you to avoid multiple selects induced by exists clause that was in Shadow's answer (which is totally correct semantically, though).

Comment: exists subqueries are faster in many occasions than joins, since the exists subquery does not fetch any data, while you need to fetch data twice in the join.

Comment: Yuri thanks for your answer too, your solution works great aswell, it's just a little bit slower than Shadow's :)

Comment: right, would be interesting to compare the two on the huge data volume